# Moving GIMP floats with arrow keys + Shift

Tags: gimp

Looking around it seems like the accelerated Shift + arrow keys movement default is 25 pixels. Somehow mine seems to be 2 pixels. Can this be customized?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys move 1px by default. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> moves in bigger increments, but the amount depends on your zoom level.

If you are zoomed into the pixel level, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrow keys moves in 2px increments, but if you zoom out if moves in progressively bigger increments. Makes sense if you think about it.

I think this behaviour was changed in newer versions. However it doesn't seem to be documented on the GIMP Docs page yet. Maybe it needs to be updated. I only discovered it by testing.

As far as I'm aware, you can't change this behaviour other than by zooming out. If there was a way it would probably be in the Preferences, but I couldn't find a setting for it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the zoom aspect of it, I just found this 25 pixel number from looking into documentation and various posts. I also couldn't find anything in the preferences, which is really too bad.